# Реализация двоичного поиска по комбинированному ключу на СИ

Tags: c, поиск, двоичный-поиск

Нужно реализовать бинарный поиск по комбинированному ключу, который состоит из двух ключей(int, char).
Ключи вот такого вида:

1. 1 b
2. 1 c
3. 1 d
4. 1 l
5. 2 b
6. 2421 v

Ну и того же типа.
Я кое-что накидал, но оно работает не правильно(даже знаю почему: 1 часть упорядочена полностью, а вот вторая только локально). Как исправить пока что сам допереть не могу.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int keyint;
    char keychar;
}t_intchar_key;

typedef struct 
{
    t_intchar_key key;
    int index;
} t_table;

int binarysearch(int a, char c, t_table *table, int n)
{
    int low, high, middle;
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (a < table[middle].key.keyint && c < table[middle].key.keychar)
            high = middle - 1;
        else if (a > table[middle].key.keyint && c > table[middle].key.keychar)
            low = middle + 1;
        else 
            return middle;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Заменить `a < table[middle].key.keyint && c < table[middle].key.keychar` на `a < table[middle].key.keyint || (a == table[middle].key.keyint && c < table[middle].key.keychar)`. И вставить это в бин поиск для одного ключа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Путаница возникает из-за того, что вы перемешиваете код сравнения с кодом поиска.

Алгоритм двоичного поиска никак не зависит от структуры ключа, если ваши ключи строго упорядочены.

В вашем случае ключи лексикографически упорядочены. Я бы советовал вам вынести логику сравнения ключей в отдельную функцию так, чтобы она была изолирована от логики самого общего алгоритма двоичного поиска и не перемешивалась с ней. Тогда путаница сразу пропадет

```
#define COMPARE(a, b) ((a > b) - (a < b))

int compare_keys(const t_intchar_key *key1, const t_intchar_key *key2)
{
  int cmp;
  if ((cmp = COMPARE(key1->keyint, key2->keyint)) != 0)
    return cmp;
  if ((cmp = COMPARE(key1->keychar, key2->keychar)) != 0)
    return cmp;
  return 0;
}
```

А дальше пишите ваш поиск в терминах функции `compare_keys`. Здесь у вас будет обычный двоичный поиск

```
int binarysearch(int a, char c, const t_table *table, int n)
{
    int low = 0, high = n - 1;
    const t_intchar_key key = { a, c }

    while (low <= high)
    {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        int cmp = compare_keys(&key, &table[middle].key);
        if (cmp < 0)
            high = middle - 1;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            low = middle + 1;
        else 
            return middle;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(Я не проверял корректность реализации самой структуры итераций в поиске.)